# Swift - Checking size of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, size

I am trying to print a line to the debugger/console to show the dimensions of the UIImageView object I have. I was trying to use the following code but get an error saying UIImageView doesn't have a member named 'size'. This was my code:

```
    @IBOutlet var Image: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()


    var imageHeight = Image.size.height
    var imageWidth = Image.size.width

print (imageHeight)
print (imageWidth)

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before we get to your question, several points:

Don't start the name of an instance variable with upper case.

Don't use "image" for the variable name of an image view. That suggests that it is a `UIImage`. It's a UIImage**View**, not a `UIImage`. Call it something like `theImageView`.

Now to your question: UIView objects do not have a size property (`UIImage` objects **do** have a size property. That might be the cause of your confusion.) They have a bounds rectangle and a frame rectangle. You can use `theImageView.bounds.size` or `theImageView.frame.size`.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot! I have now solved the problem and have set it up to print :) Also I have only just found that I can see this in the storyboard anyway :P

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
println(self.frame.height)
println(self.frame.width)
```